# How to read and print each character(with space next to it)

Tags: java

I'm trying to read and print each character with space next to it (after line 3 in the txt file). How can I add whitespace after each character?

My input file txt looks like this (ignore first 3 lines):

6
111211
211111
T.T...
......
....T.
....T.
TTT...
......

What I want to print is:

 T . T . . .

 . . . . . .

 . . . . T .

 . . . . T .

 T T T . . .

 . . . . . .

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int size; // using it for first line
    int rows; // using it for second line
    int cols; // using it for third line
    // pass the path to the file as a parameter
    FileReader fr =
            new FileReader("input1.txt");

    int i;
    while ((i=fr.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.print((char) i);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the excepted output, but I'm getting same lines from the file. I've tried using System.out.print((char) i + " "); or System.out.print((char) i + ' '); but no success. Any suggestion?

Comment: The only possible issue I could see are the linebreaks characters. Under windows you'll have to deal with `\r` and `\n` which makes this more complicated than it should be. Not sure why you're saying you get the same lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the file line wise using a [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html).

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int size; // using it for first line
    int rows; // using it for second line
    int cols; // using it for third line
    // pass the path to the file as a parameter
    BufferedReader fr = new BufferedReader(
        new FileReader("input1.txt")
    );

    // skipping 3 lines
    fr.readLine();
    fr.readLine();
    fr.readLine();

    String line = fr.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        for (char c : line.toCharArray()) {
            System.out.print(c + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
        line = fr.readLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file=new File("demo.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

        //Ignore first three lines
        int count=0;
        while(count<3){
            sc.nextLine();
            count++;
        }

        //Add space after each character in the remaining lines
        while(sc.hasNext()) {
            String line=sc.nextLine();
            char []chars=line.toCharArray();
            for(char c:chars)
                System.out.printf("%c ",c);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
T . T . . . 
. . . . . . 
. . . . T . 
. . . . T . 
T T T . . . 
. . . . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, at least on java 8, "System.out.print((char) i + " ");" should work fine.
I've just tried it right now and works fine for me.
Which java version you're using?
Otherwise you can try BufferedReader as @second suggested.

Comment: I knew this should work somehow, I have java 9 - weird